# Completion of R-integrable functions by L-integrable functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I read that: "There's an analogy between the completion of rational numbers by real numbers and the completion of Riemann integrable functions by Lebesgue integrable functions".

Can someone elaborate on that a little bit?

Answer (score 1):

Both are examples of the completion of a metric space.  In the case of the rational numbers and reals, the metric is $d(x,y) = |x-y|$.  In the case of integration on $[a,b]$, it's $d(x,y) = \int_a^b |x(t) - y(t)|\; dt$.